# Cracks in new house slab foundation, how serious?

Tags: cracks

[image]I am in the process of building a new home in North Carolina. This is slab based foundation house. The slab was poured in mid March when the temperatures were around 40-50 F. Now during the pre-drywall inspection I found that there were a number of cracks in the slab all over. In one area specific area of the slab there are few big cracks. There are also cracks in the garage and the front patio as well. Should I be concerned about these cracks? Is this a sign for any underlying big problem? Please help.[image]

Comment: What kind of steel reinforcement is in the slab--rebar or post tension cables?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I added the picture. I am not sure the difference between rebar or post tension.

Comment: Article on post tension https://www.cesinspectionstexas.com/post-tensioned-foundation/

Comment: Is this construction subject to building inspection? if so, contact the building inspection authority and find out what they are approving.

Comment: Yes the city inspection was done and it was approved. I will check what they were approving.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that looks very unusual to me. I think you need a civil
engineering consultant. It will cost something but saying "some guys on the internet said it looked bad " is worth nothing. And maybe the conclusions will be good.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Get an expert, like an architect, to review now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think the cracks are structural and will be a problem in the future.

The crack is near a “control joint”, which is used to control expansion and contraction. The control joints are spaced appropriately and doing their job, unless the contractor did not stop the reinforcing steel through the control joint.

There is obviously a heavy load coming down on the foundation near these cracks (see the built-up column of 4 - 2x’s) and is probably contributing to the settlement (movement). If you look closely, the slab is poured with the exterior foundation system. The slab is not independent, so any movement in the foundation will affect the slab.

I’d keep a journal and place marks on the floor every 4’ along the cracks. Then I’d number the marks, measure the marks, and photograph the marks.

The cracks are small, because it’s new concrete. As the house ages a year or so and goes through a winter season and has furniture moved in, those cracks will enlarge.

I’d notify the contractor in writing that it’s unacceptable and you will be maintaining a journal.

Comment: The answers above indicate to me that you back out of the purchase on the grounds that the quality of the foundation is substandard and prone to failure.

Comment: @JimStewart I doubt if you can “back out” on the possibility of future failure, but you can prepare for what will be future litigation.

Comment: Lee Sam, you surely know what recourse is available, but if the slab is supposed to have rebar in certain places and it has only mesh, how can the builder hold a customer to a purchase agreement?

Comment: @JimStewart We don’t know the rebar was omitted. They may have installed it. It would be good to have a photo during the concrete pour.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have a picture while the concrete was poured. Could it be possible they do the mesh first and put the rebars at the time of pouring?

Comment: @NewHomeOwner Not a chance. It’s too confusing the day of the pour. Was this picture taken a few days before the pour? Did Building Codes Department sign off on the pour? They are suppose to check the steel.

Comment: That’s right the picture was taken few days before the pour. I will follow up the field manager. I am assuming they did. This is with pulte homes. I made huge deposit and I don’t know if I can get out without loosing anything.

Comment: I got some reports from the builder. Is the soil test normally done prior to pouring ?

Comment: @NewHomeOwner Yes, the soils test must be done prior to pouring concrete, because the footings are designed based on the soil conditions. However, if they didn’t do one for your property, that wouldn’t surprise me because they probably did it for other adjacent lots. However, you should get a copy of the soils test they used...for future reference.

Comment: I got the report for my lot. Looks the soil test was done after the insulation barrier was placed. It was done when the lot looked like in the attached picture. Can they really do that?

Comment: Obviously we’d like to have the report prior to doing all the work designing the footings. However, if they have other soils reports for the area, they probably know what it’s going to recommend. I wouldn’t worry about when the report was completed, as opposed to what it says. (The soils report is merely confining the design of the footings.)

Comment: Btw, I see the mesh has not been completely installed in the picture.  So, they may have added the mesh and the rebar prior to concrete pour. I’d still check to see what the Building Code Inspector saw.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. Can you also point out where the rebars would have been installed before pouring. I will check the building code inspector reports. It was approved by structural engineer and not a city building inspector.

Comment: If you look on the. Right side of your picture, you can see rebar in the footings. If you look on the left side (and the back footings) you can see that no rebar is installed in the footings.

Comment: The structural engineer found that the control joints weren't cut deep enough (1"inch minimum). What do you guys think?

Comment: Concrete naturally shrinks during the curing process. If the shrinkage is not controlled, the concrete will have irregular cracks that vary widely in size. Control joints are installed to WEAKEN the concrete at set intervals and control the shrinkage cracks. When reinforcing (like wire mesh) extends through the control joints, (and the cut is less than 1” deep), then the control joint is not doing its job.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few problems in the construction photo you added: 1) wire mesh in slab, 2) wrong supports that are too far apart for wire mesh, 3) wire mesh laying on ground (vapor barrier), 4) lack of rebar in perimeter footing, 5) thickened edge of slab without proper amount of rebar, 6) no protection of vapor barrier. 7) reinforcing extends through control joints.

1) Wire mesh is not appropriate for slabs. There is a recommended ratio of reinforcing steel to quantity of concrete. You can obtain this with rebar, but not wire mesh. (That mesh is standard #4x#4/6x6 which is too small.)

2) Supports are too far apart and allow the mesh to sag and lay on the ground.

3) When mesh lays on the ground it is located in the wrong position in the slab. Reinforcing should be in the middle of the slab or in the upper half of the slab. When the concrete is poured thx contractor will have a person “hook” the mesh and try to pull it up into position. They can’t. It merely deforms the mesh and creates a small loop. You can’t move mesh through the concrete.

4) Some rebar appears in the footing adjacent to the other building. However, there is none in the other footings. The contractor may tell you that it just hasn’t been installed yet when the picture was taken. Not true. Rebar is installed prior to installing mesh. The mesh will just be in the way of installing rebar.

5) When a slab is thickened at the edge (perimeter), additional rebar is required. There is none.

6) If you have moisture problems on your slab in the future, it’s because there is no protection between the vapor barrier and the wire mesh. (Usually there is a 2” layer of sand placed on the vapor barrier to protect it from getting holes punctured in it.) When the concrete is placed, the workers will walk all over the area creating puncture holes from the wire mesh.

7) Wire mesh runs through control joints. This defeats the purpose of the control joints (does not allow proper expansion and contraction.)

Please let us know outcome.

Comment: Could this be fiber reinforced concrete? Could fiber reinforced concrete be used without rebar in a slab foundation?

Comment: @JimStewart The slab could be fiber reinforced, (or no reinforcement) but it still must be installed with good building practices. We install slabs without mesh (or any reinforcement) but we recognize good practices by decreasing the spacing of control joints, protect the vapor barrier, etc.

Comment: I would disagree in my area wire mesh is recommended for slab less than 4” thick. After looking again I would agree that the spacing is two far for the blocking of the mesh but it can be pulled up but is difficult.

Comment: @Ed Beal, so would rebar be required in the thickened edges and in the internal beams of a slab foundation which is otherwise 4" thick?

Comment: @EdBeal Everyone says the mesh can be pulled up, but it can’t. I’ve rejected many slabs that “had the mesh pulled up” but we found the mesh laying on the bottom. Mesh on the bottom of the slab is the worst place. When the slab begins to cure, it shrinks. The very top will shrink the most because it has the least resistance, while the very bottom will shrink the least because the mesh is there. (This is what creates cracks on the surface.) We use rebar (not mesh), install it in the middle of the slab, and we don’t EVER have cracks. The key is providing the proper amount of steel.

Comment: You don’t ever have cracks that are s totally BS! My dad was a contractor, I tied hundreds if not thousands of cubic feet of industrial and residential foundations including some state jobs, truck scales that were huge 6 compression tubes taken off of every truck for 4 or 5 days 24/7 not long before his passing even that job has crack with 100+K semi trucks rolling across hundreds or even thousands of times a day I am sure it passed inspection at 30 days and at 3 years, haven’t been home often but the station is still there huge slab that my dad and 3 /5 contractors completed cracks yes.

Comment: @EdBeal Your jobs all cracked? Congratulations.

Comment: Every job in the history of concrete is or will crack it is a fact, concrete keeps getting harder or having less water and will crack within a year or 45 yess I expect every slab I have poured to have cracks even the ones with fiberglass, if you have never had a crack you are younger than my grand kids and haven’t done much work in the field, just my opinion but starting working for my Dad in the early 70’s I have not seen a concrete structure that has not cracked including bridges, skyscrapers, interstate road ways and foundations for multi story buildings , if you don’t have cracks you lie!

Comment: @EdBeal So you don’t want to discuss the op’s question, you just want to try and bully me by calling me, 1) “younger than your grandkids”, 2) “haven’t done much work”, 3) liar. Instead of trying to bully people who don’t agree with you, maybe you should tell me more about learning from your father...that was convincing.

Comment: @EdBeal Those that have trouble with cracked concrete, don’t understand the difference between “reinforcing steel” and “temperature steel”.

Answer (score 1):

First I will say there are 2 types of concrete, type one has cracks and type 2 will crack later.

Your cracks are kind of unusual because the built in crack lines are not far away, I am wondering about the quality of the pour was this an area that required some hand backfilling? I ask because of the discoloring an possible grind marks. With possibly a slight concern in this area I probably not be worried because the rebar or steel mesh will keep it from moving and all concrete slabs will crack over time.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The discoloring/grinding is due to the fact that the builder is attempting to fill those cracks. But my main concern is regarding the number of these cracks. On a floor of 1400sqft I see at least 10 such cracks and other 10 which are very small that appear as lines. Some of these crack are very long.

Comment: Fine cracks are totally normal with every slab. Big cracks can show a bad mix or an area that was not properly filled and that they shoveled from a different load to fill the low spot, if there is mesh or a grid of rebar it may not be as big of a deal, the temperatures you mentioned are awesome for a good cure ,  as long as the base under the slab was well packed with some rock and even it should be ok especially if the base was well watered prior to the pour, if the base was not compacted that could be a problem if not a level base that could also be a problem these are the biggies done wrong

Comment: I just saw the photos Of the prep did not see these before. If the mesh was pulled up , fork under vapor barrier was packed well this should not have happened, did they do compression tests or slump test? I have had drivers add two much water trying to get going faster but it caused failures, maybe that is your issue I wold get a pro and a lawyer at this point if there are no compression tests taken every yard.

Comment: thank you so much for the valuable feedback. Is that compression test for the land/soil? I will ask the builder. Can you suggest what the test would reveal?

Comment: In some areas tubes of concrete are required to be pulled and crushed with a hydraulic press and the crush point is recorded this is mostly on multi story and commercial buildings but I have lived in an area that it was required for residential.

Answer (score 1):

One additional suggestion would be to conduct a radon gas test to understand the levels at your specific property. DIY tests are not very expensive, and even professional tests by licensed testers are